# Constant running job with interrupts, best methodology

Tags: c#, .net, batch-processing

Problem :  track three states during long running process.
1) was an EOD (End of day) signal to send email reports received for a given day
2) during the same day was a new signal received to send revised reports (increase a revision number
3) was a signal received while a send was taking place, if so just warn user that an EOD signal is being processed.

After an End of day signal is received, at the end of the actual day... midnight, all variables are reset

Currently being handled with three separate booleans.  Question is, is there a more efficient method of tracking these three conditions in this infinite loop without using so many boolean variables.

Some of the code since it is to much to post it all, but here is the jist:

```
public class job
{
    private bool receivedEndOfDaySignal = false;
    private bool receivedEodOfDaySignalSend = false;
    private bool receivedEodOfDaySignalDuringSend = false;

    public void RunThisJob(IJobData JobData, IJobStatus Status)
    {
         // job setup code.
         // listener for incoming signals
         Helper.OnSignalReceived += Helper_OnSignalReceived;



         // loop for constant run
           for (; ; )
            {
                //We're still cooking
                Helper.StillGoing();

                //wait till the email send is supposed to execute
                Helper.WaitUntilTime(RunTime);

                //Send the mail
                SendMail();

                // reset signal booleans
                receivedEodOfDaySignalSend = receivedEodOfDaySignalDuringSend = false;

    }

    bool Helper_OnSignalReceived(IJobSignal signal, BatchWaitType waitType)
    {
        //Which?
        switch (signal.Code.ToUpper())
        {
            case "ENDOFDAY":
                // Acknowledge the end of day signal 
                // if end of day received more than once before being reset.
                if (receivedEodOfDaySignalDuringSend)
                {
                    Helper.Logger.Log(LogStatus.Info, "Batch", "An END OF DAY signal was already received. ");
                    Helper.Status.AcknowledgeSignal(signal);
                    return true;
                }
                // when an eod signal is received and revision count has been initialized increase the count.
                // only initialized after first eod signal received and not when another receiving during a send
                if (revisionCount != null) revisionCount++;
                // set all the flags when EOD comes through even though some will still be set
                receivedEndOfDaySignal = receivedEodOfDaySignalSend = receivedEodOfDaySignalDuringSend = true;
                Helper.Status.AcknowledgeSignal(signal);
                return true;
        }

        //Still here?
        return false;
    }

}
```

The listener sets the appropriate variables for the running process... what I have does in fact work.  Just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I don't think an endless loop is **ever** a good idea...

Comment: What are your signals trying to accomplish?  Wouldn't the program be better able to determine end-of-day by itself?

Comment: The signals are to determine when to send EOD reports... unfortunately it's not really the end of a business day.  Keep in mind that most of this architecture is already written (by someone else) and cannot be changed.  The signal is a trigger on the loop to perform an action.  In this case, to send out emails... if more than one EOD signal is received, it increases the revision number of the report and sends out a new one.  The next biz day the whole process can be repeated.  In long running jobs you are always in a loop unless the service is stopped, or interrupted by user actions.

Comment: Root of the question I suppose is, is there a better way to track states where the state can be more than just true or false. with the possibility of more states being created later.  without over complication or reduced readability

Comment: @ Mario De Schaepmeester  The process also accepts a quit signal to tell it to stop.